# How to make the images not move other than the mouseovered one

Tags: html, css, list, hover

In a list that is displayed inline and formed of images, how do you make the images other than the mouseovered one, not move? When i put mouse over a image, the images at the sides also moves. how can i make them not move? (I set the CSS settings for the image that

```
img {
     width:42px;
     height:60px; 
    }
img:hover {
    width:62px;
    height:80px;
```

So it just resize when mouse put over.)

Comment: So you want the image to expand and overlap other images onhover?

Comment: No, the image onhover must go over the images beside

Comment: That's what overlap means. Look at [CSS positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), specifically z-index.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you looking for ?

```
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.30);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.30);
  -o-transform: scale(1.30);
  transform: scale(1.30);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xn96djc3/)